# Read data into structured array with multiple dtypes

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, pyodbc

I'm trying to read some data from SQL (using pyodbc) into a numpy structured array (I believe a structured array is required due to the multiple dtypes).

```
import pyodbc
import numpy as np
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};Server=SERVER;Database=DB;Trusted_Connection=Yes;')
cursor = cnxn.cursor()
sql_ps = "select a, b from table"
cursor.execute(sql_positions)
p_data = cursor.fetchall()
cnxn.close

ndtype = np.dtype([('f1','>f8'),('f2','|S22')])
p_data = np.asarray(p_data, dtype=ndtype)
```

However this returns:

```
TypeError: expected a readable buffer object
```

If I load into the array as a tuple

```
p_data_tuple = np.asarray([tuple(i) for i in p_data], dtype=ndtype)
```

It works, however `p_data_tuple` is an array of tuples, as opposed to a 2d array, meaning I cannot call elements using `p_data_tuple[0,1]`

Does anyone know how I can either put the data returned directly into a str array with multiple dtypes, or convert the array of tuples into a 2d array of multiple dtypes, or some other solution?

Thanks

Comment: What happens if you run the query via pandas: `df = pd.read_sql_query(sql_ps, cnxn)`

Comment: I can take that and then convert the return into an array using `p_data_2 = df.asmatrix(['a','b']) ` but doesn't seem to let me specify the dtype, which for `p_data_2` would be `object`.

Comment: *"It works, however p_data_tuple is an array of tuples, as opposed to a 2d array, meaning I cannot call elements using p_data_tuple[0,1]"*  That is what happens when you create a structured array as you do.  It will be a *one-dimensional* array of structures.  If the data types of the fields in the structure are not all the same, you *can't* access it as a two-dimensional array.

Comment: You access 'columns' by dtype name, eg `data['f1']`.  And records by number, `data[0]`.

Comment: Thanks Warren, so presumably then the only solution is to read the data into an array `p_data = np.asarray(p_data)` and then slice it up into arrays  with the same dtypes

Comment: From your original question "..or some other solution?", maybe you can explain your use case more, but I think I'd recommend using `pandas`.  It is built upon `numpy`, so you can always convert to native numpy objects, but has a lot of conveniences built in for data alignment and type handling.

Comment: I'll read up on pandas in that case, thanks Colin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `cursor.fetchall` returns a list of records.  A record is 'Row objects are similar to tuples, but they also allow access to columns by name' (http://mkleehammer.github.io/pyodbc/).  Sounds like a namedtuple to me, though the class details may be different.

```
sql_ps = "select a, b from table"
cursor.execute(sql_positions)
p_data = cursor.fetchall()
cnxn.close
```

just for fun let's change the `dtype` to use the same field names as the `sql`:

```
ndtype = np.dtype([('a','>f8'),('b','|S22')])
```

This doesn't work, presumably because the `tuple-like` record isn't a real tuple.

```
p_data = np.array(p_data, dtype=ndtype)
```

So instead we convert each record to a tuple.  Structured arrays take their data as a list of tuples.

```
p_data = np.array([tuple(i) for i in p_data], dtype=ndtype)
```

Now you can access the data by field or by row

```
p_data['a']    # 1d array of floats
p_data['b'][1]  # one string
p_data[10]   # one record
```

A record from `p_data` displays as a tuple, though it does actually have a `dtype` like the parent array.

There's a variant on structured arrays, `recarray` that adds the ability to access fields by attribute name, e.g. `p_rec.a`.  That's even closer to the dp cursor record, but doesn't add much otherwise.

So this structured array is quite similar to your source sql table - with fields and rows.  It's not a 2d array, but indexing by field name is similar to indexing a 2d array by column number.

`pandas` does something similar, though it often resorts to using `dtype=object` (like the pointers of Python lists).  And it keeps track of 'row' labels.